# Count the requests processed by a Mule flow

Tags: java, spring, mule

I'm using Mule ESB 3.4. I want to develop a custom Java component that counts how many requests are received by a flow. The flow would e.g. be something like this:

```
http inbound-endpoint -> counter -> vm-outbound-endpoint
```

First of all, the actual variable containing the counter should be stored in memory. Then it might be printed to the log or inserted into a DB (It's not important for now). What I'm after is a clean design that I can later re-use to store a more complex application-global state (based on the number and the content of received messages) and implement a more complex logic.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to implement this?  What, if any, issues have you come across?

Comment: Nope I haven't yet. The only thing I can think of is a static variable in the component class. However that would make it hard to access it from outside the component e.g. from another flow : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to this problem is to create the counter variable as a singleton Spring bean ( e.g. of class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger ) and then inject it into a custom Mule component again via Spring. The component can be defined with prototype-scope, and can safely run something like counter.incrementAndGet() every time a Message traverses it. In that way the counter would -at any time- hold the number of messages that passed through the flow.

Since a Spring bean can be any POJO you like, you can easily extend this design to allow a more complex state to be stored. The stored object has of course to expose thread-safe operations.

Answer (score 0):

For a clean and decoupled approach you can use Server Notifications:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications

You just need to add the listener for endpoint messages that can be a Spring bean and store the value there.

Comment: From the link you posted "These notifications have some impact on performance, so they are disabled by default". Besides, I'd like to have access to the messages as they flow: something like a message observer that is able to keep a state.

Comment: You have access to the message in the notifications and notifications listeners are actually what you are asking for.

Comment: Still, if the Mule doc says that it's gonna have an impact on performance, I'm sure it's not what I want.