# Log count of messages received from multithread

Tags: mule

I'm looking for some way to log the number of messages i receive in several inbounds from udp multithreading :

```
<flow name="transaccion" doc:name="transaccion">
    <set-variable variableName="#[count]" value="#[0]" />
    <composite-source>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3001" connector-ref="udpConnector" doc:name="3001"/>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3002" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="3002"/>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3003" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="3003"/>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3004" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="3004"/>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3005" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="3005"/>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3006" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="3006"/>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3007" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="3007"/>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3008" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="3008"/>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3009" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="3009"/>
        <udp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="3010" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="3010"/>
    </composite-source>
    <set-variable variableName="#[counter]" value="#[count]+1" /> 
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <set-payload value="#['Hello, ' + message.payload + '. Today is the end of the world. ']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

    <logger message="message #[payload:java.lang.String] received from #[function:hostname] #[function:ip] #[function:count]  count: #[variable:counter]   "    level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

This is an example, i tried some ways and or get null , or doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have the counter in the app registry, not local to the flow. One way to do that would be a simple singleton-scoped Spring bean.

flow:

```
<spring:beans>
  <spring:bean id="counterBean" class="my.test.Counter" />
</spring:beans>

<logger message="message count: #[app.registry.counterBean.count()] " level="INFO"/>
```

class:

```
public class Counter {

    private int count = 0;
    public synchronized int count() {
       count++;
       return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit detailed, i try to create a flow with the bean and logger, but : Invalid content was found starting with element 'logger'.

How bean increment +1 its count if is out of the flow?

Is the syntax #[app.registry.counterBean.count()]  correct? mule confus me

Comment: Put the logger inside your flow, and it will look up & call the bean from registry.

Comment: You should consider adding a synchronization mechanism there to avoid concurrency problems.

Comment: Ah, yes. That is true when your flow can run separate threads for different inputs. Added synchronized to the count method. Also Guido's answer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Spring bean as an AtomicInteger

```
<bean id="messageCounter" class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

And then increment it in the flow like this

```
<expression-component doc:name="messageCounter plus plus">
    app.registry.messageCounter.incrementAndGet();
</expression-component>
```

Kindof same problem here: [Count the requests processed by a Mule flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709931/count-the-requests-processed-by-a-mule-flow)